# Error message on new installation php,mysql,apache on ubuntu 12.04 with joomla.2.5

Tags: php, ubuntu, joomla, joomla2.5, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed apache, php and mysql on ubuntu 12.04 system, and I managed to run a helloworld.php. This file was located in /var/www and the program ran correctly.
Then I transferred a joomla 2.5 application that I had from windows 7 wamp to ubuntu 12.04 and when I run the application, I got the following message:

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown
>   on line 0 Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/offer_e_shop_1/index.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0

also I need to mention that the mysql was correctly installed in mysql as believe. 
what do I need to do here?
oh and I forgot to mention that this was the tutorial I read to do so
http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts-lamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default owner of the `/var/www` and its sub-folders is the user `root` change it to `apache` using the command:

```
sudo chown -R apache /var/www/offer_e_shop_1
```

If this doesn't work try to give full access to your code:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/offer_e_shop_1
```

I personally always reset the folder locations to my desktop. Here is a helpful tutorial:
http://blip.tv/step4wd/ubuntu-apache2-name-hosting_en-5922406

Comment: ye that solved the problem. Thank you!.but 777 means read write?

Comment: @themhz - be careful with using chmod 777. Not a very secure method